# Problem with a commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I want to draw this diagram:

[image: here]

And I have tried out the following code which is not working:

```
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    & E \arrow{r}{u} \arrow{dr}{$\pi$} 
    & {E^'}\arrow{dl}{$\pi^'$}\\
    & X  
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: There should be a `u` over the arrow from `E` to `E'` in the picture.

Comment: Note that `E^{'}` is wrong; it should be `E'`. Also the arguments to `\arrow` are already in math mode, so `$` should not be used in them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need three columns. But also to vertically align `\pi` and `\pi'`.

With `\setheight{x}{y}` we typeset `x`, but as if its vertical dimensions were those of `y`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\setheight}[2]{\smash{#1}\vphantom{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
E \arrow[rd, "\pi"'] \arrow[rr, "u"] &   & E' \arrow[ld, "\setheight{\pi'}{\pi}"] \\
& X
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A concise solution which just goes the extra mile to look a little bit cleaner; great answer!

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
     E \arrow[rr,"u"] \arrow[dr,"\pi"'] 
    & & {E'}\arrow[dl,"\pi'"]\\
    & X & \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
E \ar[rr,"u"] \ar[dr,"\pi" '] 
    &   &   E'\ar[dl, "\pi'"]  \\ 
    & x &    
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
E \ar[rr,"u"] \ar[dr, "\pi", sloped]
    &   &   E'\ar[dl, "\pi'",sloped]  \\
    & x &
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here there is my proposal.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2 em,column sep=1em]
E \arrow[rd, "\pi"'] \arrow[rr, "u"] &   & E' \arrow[ld, "\pi'"] \\
& x &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### ADDENDUM: a variant with `xy` package.

It is possible to have `\pi` and `\pi'` on the same horizontal line (nearly by eye - see the distances `.46` and `.4`) using `xy` package with the same tips (see option *cmtip*) of `tikz-cd` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
E \ar[rr]^{u}
\ar[dr]_(.46){\pi} 
&& E'\ar[dl]^(.4){\pi'} \\
& X }
\end{document}
```